# Error expected ':' when running sbt command in terminal

Tags: java, scala, github, sbt

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/clulab/reach) from github on my own data. I cloned git into IntelliJ, imported Scala there too. [The running manual](https://github.com/clulab/reach/wiki/Running-REACH) says "NOTE: As of version 1.4.0, Reach now requires a Processors Server process to be started, in a separate JVM, before running Reach."

So, I installed sbt and tried to run 
`sbt 'run-main org.clulab.processors.server.ProcessorServer'`
from terminal to start a Server. I got the following error

```
[error] Expected ';'
[error] run-main org.clulab.processors.server.ProcessorServer
[error]                                                      ^
```

After googling, I found some solutions regarding the line ending. I tried to add CR in the end (ctrl-V and Return), it did not help.

I do not know, maybe I shouldn't do that in terminal? I have never use Scala, sbt, or java before. So, I am super confused.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Try `runMain` instead of `run-main`.

Comment: @MarioGalic I think it worked. Thank you! But now it cannot find org.clulab.processors.server.ProcessorServer. Where does it refer to? Should it be in cloned files?

Comment: They use outdated version of sbt: https://github.com/clulab/reach/blob/a02c74c2522f712fd32f81036bfce1f60d600d2f/project/build.properties which is why their commands might not match current practices (e.g. `runMain` vs `run-main`). AndI weren't able to find `ProcessorServer` class in any of their Scala repos that I look at, for me it looks that the instruction is simply outdated. I would ask them on their GitHub what is going on.

Comment: It seems it _used to be there_ if you look at the fork: https://github.com/allenai/processors-corenlp/blob/master/corenlp/src/main/scala/org/clulab/processors/server/ProcessorServer.scala - but it isn't anymore in more recent code: https://github.com/clulab/processors/search?q=ProcessorServer&unscoped_q=ProcessorServer - definitely outdated manual