# Why does sbt fail with "Expected ';'"?

Tags: sbt, chisel

When I run example chisel design from the [learning-journey](https://github.com/Intensivate/learning-journey) project, I am seeing error as following:

```
    $ ./run-examples.sh SimpleALU
    ...
    [info] Set current project to chisel-tutorial (in build file:/home/fchen/work/learning-journey/)
    [error] Expected ';'
    [error] test:run-main examples.Launcher SimpleALU
    [error]                                          ^
```

Does anyone know what might have gone wrong?

Comment: The following link gives a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944441/error-expected-when-running-sbt-command-in-terminal

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `run-main`, one should use `runMain`. `run-main` was deprecated and removed from SBT several years ago.

Just as a mild warning, that [repo](https://github.com/Intensivate/learning-journey/) is a little dated, using Chisel 3.1.8 when the latest release is 3.3.2 with 3.4.0 set to be released soon. Technically 3.1.8 is only a year old but the last year has seen a lot of development.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Edit `run-examples.sh` to use `sbt runMain` instead.

---

[learning-journey/run-examples.sh](https://github.com/Intensivate/learning-journey/blob/master/run-examples.sh) looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
args=$@
sbt -v "test:run-main examples.Launcher $args"
```

That basically boils down to executing `run-main` command. That's no longer available in the recent sbt versions.

```
$ sbt -V
sbt version in this project: 1.3.13
sbt script version: 1.3.13

$ sbt run-main whatever
...
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Not a valid command: run-main
[error] Not a valid project ID: run-main
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: run-main (similar: runMain, bgRunMain, fgRunMain)
[error] run-main
[error]         ^
```

That's exactly the error, isn't it?